# I don't know what to do with the else in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

```
elif num < ord('a'):
  num += 26
translated += chr(num)
else:   
translated += symbol
return translated
mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()
key = getKey()
```

when ever I run this code as it is, I get an error message saying "invalid syntax"(highlights the 'else:'). However if a shift the else line a few spaces in, i get an error saying "unexpected indent"(highlights the 'else:' once again) what should i do, i have already tried shifting the else a few lines in, i have also tried to run the part in the next line still didn't work

Comment: Is this the full code?

Comment: @sPaz no this is just the last part

Comment: If you are not using `else:`, take it out.

Comment: The indentation is all wrong. And you should really show it starting from the "if".

Comment: Correct indentation is vital in Python.  You might want to read http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properly indenting your code helps. ...

```
elif num < ord('a'):
    num += 26
    translated += chr(num)
else:   
    translated += symbol
    return translated
 # you are returning here ... so the block has to be fixed ...   
 mode = getMode()
 message = getMessage()
 key = getKey()
```

Comment: i have tried that out but i am still getting an error

Comment: see my corrected indentation ...

Comment: would be nice if you accept the answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely in the line of code:

```
translated += chr(num)
```

Since it's not indented, it will always run.  So the  else:  doesn't have any 'if' associated with it.